# Rendering an asp.net user control in a Panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I created this asp.net user control (just a sample for this stack overflow post)

HTML:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ucBTN.ascx.vb" Inherits="EBC_SAK_MVV_BTN.web.ucBTN" %>

<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLeft" runat="server" Width="200" Height="100" CssClass="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary" Text="Button-Left" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnMiddle" runat="server" Width="200" Height="100" CssClass="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary" Text="Button-Middle" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRight" runat="server" Width="200" Height="100" CssClass="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary" Text="Button-Right" />
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Class ucBTN
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Public Property TextLeft As String
    Public Property TextMiddle As String
    Public Property TextRight As String
End Class
```

When I use this user control in a page it works (test.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/EBC.Master" CodeBehind="TEST.aspx.vb" Inherits="EBC_SAK_MVV_BTN.web.TEST" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/ucBTN.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ucBTN" %>
<uc1:ucBTN runat="server" ID="myBTN" />
```

But when I add a panel to my page and add my user control to this panel it keeps blank:

HTML:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim BTN As New ucBTN
BTN.TextLeft = "LEFT"
BTN.TextMiddle = "MIDDLE"
BTN.TextRight = "RIGHT"
Panel1.Controls.Add(BTN)
End Sub
```

I want to create dozends of these controls during runtime - how do I add them to my panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use PlaceHolder instead of panel

in user control use:

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
```

in code behind use:

```
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(BTN)
```

Comment: Well, does not work either - although I understand that I have to use a PlaceHolder if I want to add controls. When adding a new button AND my user control to the placeholder only the button is shown.

Comment: string _ascxPath = @"~/ucBTN.ascx";
Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
Panel1.Controls.Add(control);